# Is there a generalisation possible for arithmetic progression with dynamic cyclic difference?

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic-progressions

Arithmetic progression with dynamic cyclic difference

Eg: $1, 3, 6, 11, 18, 20, 23, 28, 35...$

Here the difference cycle through $[2, 3, 5, 7]$

Is it possible through generalize it?

Like we generalize regular arithmetic progression as $a + nd$.

Comment: Notice that if you erase three terms between each first of cycle you get $1, 18, 35$, which are actually an arithmetic progression. So you get four arithmetic progressions in this case. Are you able to get the generalization formula from here?

Comment: @AnilCh yes we can get four generalizations, but how to interweave them into a single generalization.

Comment: You can do it through a piecewise function that defines $a_n$ and it depends on $n \mod 4$, and each part is the different arithmetic progression. That's a single generalization. If you meant to write another thing, I'd ask you to clarify what you mean by a single generalization and why the four arithmetic progression aren't enough.

Comment: @AnilCh there are equation for individual lines and there are equations for family of lines. There is great mathematical utility in combining different equations into a single equation

Comment: If what you want is a 'single expression of one line', then for the cycle $[2,3]$ something like $a_n = a_0 + 5 \lfloor n/2 \rfloor + 2 \cdot 1_{n \mod 2 == 1}$ where $a_0$ is the first value and $1_{n\mod 2 = 1}$ is the [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function). For any cycle you can work something like this, it's just a bit harder to read than a simple piecewise expression and both are mathematically the same object in the end, it just changes the notation. That's why I insist that four arithmetic progr. were already a single generalization.

Comment: @MrGreenGold I have put up an answer... how do you feel about it?

Answer (score 0):

You may write it as $\lbrace a_i : a_1 = 1, a_i = a_{i-1} + S(i-1 \bmod{4}), S = \lbrace (0,7),(1,2),(2,3),(3,5) \rbrace \rbrace \rbrace $

This is the easiest in my view as primes have a really fuzzy and slightly confusing distribution and hence a general formula can't be made for primes (but when 2 and 3 are excluded, we have $6k + 1$ and $6k + 5$ as some generic forms of primes, but those to hold exceptions). Here, the advantage is that the function the set $S$ returns the required primes in cycles of $4$ (as how you've made the A.P.) so you only need to get the image for $i-1 \bmod{4}$ from the set $S$ and  add it to the preceding term.